BLDC Gate Drive cross conduction
I am making a BLDC controler using 6 MOSFETs and 3 gate-drivers.
I have the following issue:
When the Low-Side MOSFET gate is active the High-Side gate is also active. It's not a problem from the gate driver because I can see a high logic-state on the High-Side gate even with the pin left floating. I suspect a cross-talk issue, but the traces are fairly spaced (5-10mm) and I'm low on frequency (16KHz).





First scope is the problem and second one is with the pin left floating.
Blue trace is UL signal to gate driver, Yellow trace is UH signal to gate driver, Red trace is the gate voltage of the High-Side MOSFET, the green trace is the gate of the Low-Side MOSFET.
Any idea where it might come from and how to solve this?

Is there a reason for the accordion traces on your PCB?

I don't know what the waveforms are showing. Perhaps they could be labeled to clarify what's being shown? || Why does the schematic appear twice, is there a difference we should be looking for?

In addition to @TimWilliams questions, I'm not clear on what you mean here: When the Low-Side MOSFET gate is active the High-Side gate is also active. It's not a problem from the gate driver because I can see a high logic-state on the High-Side gate even with the pin left floating   When you drive the high side UH_PWM pin low, you're still seeing the high side output drive the gate high?  What pin are you leaving floating?  Are you measuring the gate to source of the FET, HO to VS since the high side drive is referenced to the source?

Also, the high-side drive is bootstrapped, so it relies on the low side switching to charge the bootstrap cap to provide power to the upper driver.  If your low side isn't switching, it's unlikely that you have drive to the high side FET.

Thanks for all the answers, the signals labels have been added. On the second scope, I leave the pin 7 of the IC floating and I still see some gate voltage on it when driving UL. All measurements are referenced to GND. Yes the High-Side is bootstrapped, but even without the bootstrap capacitor, I still see voltage on the High-Side MOSFET's gate. The accordion traces are for length matching since I want to raise the switching frequency if possible.

@VerdaClement Are you measuring the high side gate or gate to source?

@JohnD I'm measuring the High-Side gate

@VerdaClement If you're not measuring gate to source, i.e. HO to VS, you're not measuring the top FET drive.  It's irrelevant what HO is to ground since Vgs is what matters.  You could turn the low side on, ensure that VS is at 0 V, (or ground VS) then see if HO is zero when HIN is low. Just don't ground VS and try to turn the high side on.  Maybe use a current limited supply at a safe level to prevent damage.

@JohnD I measured using a differential probe. I really appreciate the help :)
In the end, the problem is called "self turn-on phenomenon" I found plenty of documentation for this issue. Thanks all for your help.
